# Query Number of connection C3P0 acquire at the start

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I wanted to know whether a c3P0 will create some initial pool of database connection with the program start up?

If I set the initialPoolSize to 0, when I start the program it will not create any initial pool. It will start creating database connection when the program needs to get some information from database.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

To not have c3p0 acquire any Connections on start-up, you'd have to set both `initialPoolSize` and `minPoolSize` to zero. If `initialPoolSize` is less than `minPoolSize`, it is ignored.

Comment: My initialPoolSize -> 0 and minPoolSize -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20
But in my catalina logs I can still see the message Initializing c3p0 pool... during the program start up and I'm able to see the error from DB (DB is temporarily down) inside the logs.